# Funeral Mass vs. Mass for the Deceased

Tags: catholicism, mass, funeral

My mother is recently deceased. My siblings want just a Mass said for our recently deceased mother. Is there a Mass for the Deceased other than a funeral?

Comment: It's a "funeral" if a body is present. The "Mass for the Dead"/"Mass for the deceased" is the intention or the particular prayers.

Comment: My condolences for your loss. In Catholic practice, a funeral should ordinarily be done (and it should also be done if your mother wished it). Additional Masses for the dead are often requested afterwards (on anniversaries, etc)

Comment: The faithful may request a Mass to be said for the intentions of any deceased member of the Church. We may also request, if the priest is willing, to have that intention within a Requiem Mass offered up for someone too.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a [Requiem Mass (*Missa pro defunctis*)](http://www.sanctamissa.org/en/resources/requiem/requiem-mass-daily-mass-for-the-dead.html) can be said for the soul of a deceased person, and Requiem Masses needn't be accompanied by a funeral/burial.

Sometimes, Requiem Masses are said with a catafalque, which is something that looks like a coffin, but isn't; catafalques are to remind the faithful of the deceased person:
[image: catafalque]

Comment: Particularly like the addition of the picture.  A more concise answer than mine.

Answer (score 3):

### A  Mass that includes your mother via [Intentions for the Mass](http://www.catholicnewsagency.com/column/mass-intentions-1800/) may fit your needs.

One way to remember your mother in a Mass is to contact the local parish, or the parish where she passed away, and make a request that the *[intentions of the Mass](http://www.ewtn.com/library/liturgy/zlitur70.htm)* include her by name.  (Anecdote: we have done this a number of times in the past four years since the death of my father-in-law, in his home parish, most recently on the day before Thanksgiving this year.)  You could also ask to have a private Mass for, celebrated with your family, but that requires coordination with a priest.

#### For the Intentions of this Mass ...

The practice of praying for various individuals in the faith community is supported by a requirement from Canon Law.

> Whenever a priest celebrates Mass, he has at least two intentions. 
>   The first intention is to celebrate the Mass according to what the
>   Church does.  [The second is to apply the grace of that Mass towards a
>   specific need, whether it be a person(s), living or dead, baptized or
>   not, or a special need.](http://www.catholicnewsagency.com/column/mass-intentions-1800/)  Every parish pastor is required, by Canon
>   Law, to offer at least one Mass on Sunday for the needs and intentions
>   of his parishioners (Can. 534 §1).

Based on our family experience, you should contact your mother's parish, or your local parish, and ask to have her included in the intentions of a Mass that you will attend.

---

> Can. 534 §1. After a pastor has taken possession of his parish, he is
>   obliged to apply a Mass for the people entrusted to him on each Sunday
>   and holy day of obligation in his diocese. If he is legitimately
>   impeded from this celebration, however, he is to apply it on the same
>   days through another or on other days himself.
>
> §2. A pastor who has the care of several parishes is bound to apply
>   only one Mass for the entire people entrusted to him on the days
>   mentioned in §1.
>
> §3. A pastor who has not satisfied the obligation mentioned in §§1 and
>   2 is to apply as soon as possible as many Masses for the people as he
>   has omitted

Comment: A particular Mass has one principal intention for which the priest offers it, which is not the same (or even required to be included) in the Universal Prayer/Prayers of the Faithful

Comment: The actual intention (required by Canon Law, etc) doesn't have to be verbally announced. The priest must specifically mentally intend it at least certain parts in the Eucharistic prayer; it's similar to how you can pray a Rosary for an intention without having to audibly announce it. A parish also must keep records of Mass intentions that have been requested and when they are actually made

Comment: that can be customary in various churches, but it's not actually required. Other places print the intention in the bulletin, etc (also not required)

Comment: @eques I deleted some of the bits that are customary at our parish, per your points.   I had assumed that this was standard form, but it will vary.